# Load More Option In TableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to implement Load More Option in tableView . I had received data from the web services in XML and i had parsed the XML files through the XML Api URLs and display the data in the UITableView.

API URL is like:-

> http://www.xyz.com/api_tm.php?page_id=%d

"%d" this is the place holder for the Page No. there are 10 pages from (1 to 10) and each page has 15 News which i display on UITableView.

Now I want "LoadMore" option in the table view for when user click on load more option then  value of "%d"place holder is changing from 1 to 2 and so on and load the next 15 news of page 2 on the tableView with the preexist news of page 1 and again showing the load more option for next pages.

Can any one suggest me the way to implement the "LoadMore" option in the UITableView.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Accept some answers to the questions you asked earlier.

Comment: Do not re-post your question. If you aren't getting any answers then add more information or offer a bounty. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Instead use Load More Button in Footer View of tableview & reload tableview for every page count.

or Try this Links

https://github.com/sishen/LoadMoreTableFooterView

https://github.com/kwylez/LoadMore

Answer (score 2):

Or try the three20 framework

http://thre20.info

https://github.com/facebook/three20

There is a class named TTTableViewController that implements Load more button.

Answer (score 1):

When LoadMore is clicked parse xml with next %d value and add them in your array and reload your table `[tablename reloaddata];`

Comment: See i'm new to iphone development so how can i implement LoadMore Option in TableView...

Comment: Your data must be stored in an array. When loadmore is clicked, start parsing of your next xml file, store that data in temporary array. Then, add that data in the array you are using for your table. and reload your table afterwards [tablename reloaddata]. This must be helpful to you.

Comment: How can i add "loadMore" button on my 11th row but i'm getting 10 news in 1 page no. of rows in section method return array count which is 10 so it generates only 10 rows how can i implement button on 11th cell plz suggest me the proper way ...

Comment: it's very simple... in number of rows in section, return [arrayName count] + 1;

Comment: I'm doing the same but when i run the program and scroll down the table View then about reaching down the final cell which is 11th one application stuck and showning this SIGABRT at the statment:              WorkInfo *aWorkInfo = [appDelegate.newsArray objectAtIndex.row];  so what should i'll do after getting this suggest me the solution to over came this prob...

Comment: use condition if(indexpath.row <= ([array count] - 1)){WorkInfo *aWorkInfo = [appDelegate.newsArray objectAtIndex.row]; } else add your addmore more.

Answer (score 1):

I think use face book's "pull down to refresh" way is the most user-friendly approach, only different it yours will be "pull up to load more".

Answer (score 1):

Just add a button in 11 th cell by using indexPath.row

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {

      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

       if (indexPath.row == 11) 
       {
           UIButton *btnMore   = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; 
           btnMore.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
           btnMore.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0];
                [btnMore setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,44)];

           [cell addSubview:btnMore];
           [btnMore release];
           return cell;
       }    
}
```