# How to add a button to the last row of a tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm unable to find the solution how can I add this "Load More" button in a `UITableViewCell`.

Like "More Results..." option in this app

> http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/zdnet/id425580940?mt=8

Hope someone can help me...

Comment: what you exactly want to do. Do you want that when you scroll the table down then load more appears till new results are not come.

Comment: i am unable to place that button in Tableview.As like if i am having 10 rows in table then how can i place that "loadmore" option on the 11th row.? can u give me some link or some piece of code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load More Option In TableView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936968/load-more-option-in-tableview)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an easier way to accomplish this would be to adopt the `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` and `tableView:heightForFooterInSection` methods and return a view with the "Load More Results" button.

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        // create a footer view so that we can add it later when we need to
        loadMoreView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
        UIButton* moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [[moreButton titleLabel] setText:@"Load More Results"];
        [moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMore:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [loadMoreView addSubview:moreButton];            

        // other init code here
    }
    return self
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tv viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)s
{
    return loadMoreView;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tv heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)s
{
    return [loadMoreView frame].size.height; // or 40 since that's what we set it to
}
```

Comment: I think, this is a more cleaner approach. But you also need to specify the frame for UIButton; moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160.0, 40.0);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your normal content, make your last cell a UIButton.  When the user clicks it, update your data source with new information (don't forget to update the number of rows in each section), and call reloadData on the tableview.  Always keep the button in the bottommost cell.

How you update your data source depends totally on your implementation.

To add a button to a UITableViewCell you can do this in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == dataForCells.count + 1){ // Assume dataForCells is an NSArray holding your data.  Initially it should hold 10 objects, then after clicking this button it will be 20, 30, etc. as you load data in load10MorePressed.  However, this depends on your implementation.  You could be storing your data in some other way.
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LoadMoreCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectInset(cell.frame, 5, 5);
        [button setTitle:@"Load 10 More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(load10MorePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:button];
    } else {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NormalCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Setup your normal data cells here
    }
}
```

But you need to make sure you have a method named load10MorePressed:

```
-(IBAction)load10MorePressed:(id)sender{
    NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dataForCells];
    for (int x=0; x<10; x++){
        [temp addObject:[Create new objects here.  Depends on your implementation, probably downloading from someplace...]];
    }
    self.dataForCells = temp;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And finally, don't forget to return the number of cells in your tableview:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (section == 0){
        return dataForCells.count + 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but i am new to iPhone development so i am unable to place that button in Tableview.As like if i am having 10 rows in table then how can i place that "loadmore" option on the 11th row.? can u give me some link or some piece of code.

Comment: I have updated my response to show how you can create the cell, and load more data.

Comment: i'm getting data from XML in this ways (i'm getting 10 news in each page ,there are 10 pages and i'm getting these news through changes the value of "%@"(placeholder) in the api so i'm again not able to do this i really thanks for ur response i worked on this solution u give me but i'm again unable to under stand this issue (i have an API like:- http://www.xyz.com/?page=%@ i'm changing the value of this placeholder "%@" for 1 to 10 for ten pages each page having 10 news so my question is i able to parse to display in table but how i set after 10 news loadmore button will display )...

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge you can do like this.

put a button loadmore .When user clicked on the button  in buttonAction take a BOOL variable and then use the [tableview reloadData];.And in numberofrowsintableview method check the BOOL variable.If it is yes then return the (Ex:)10+previousrows.Pass the data to it also

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem :-
    What you have to do  is add an activity indicator below table view.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (indexPath.row ==[array count] -1 ) { //this method will get called when you will scroll to the bottom of your table view 
        [self sendRequestMethod];   

    }
    else {
        //NSLog(@"not nearest row");
        //[self remove];
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)sendRequestMethod
{
    [self.newTableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [indicator startAnimating];//make sure you start your indicator now perform what you want to do IN my case I am sending a request to server

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(responseSuccedMethod:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(responseFailedMethod:)];
    [networkQueue addOperation: request];
    [networkQueue go];


}

-(void)responseSuccedMethod:(ASIHTTPRequest *)req
{   
    [self.newTableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [indicator stopAnimating];  
    [newTableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but i am new to iPhone development so i am unable to place that button in Tableview.As like if i am having 10 rows in table then how can i place that "loadmore" option on the 11th row.? can u give me some link or some piece of code.